# How to activate a function before its nested

Tags: python, function, tkinter

my code its almost complete but it will not initiate unless I activate the first function once

I want the program to run as long as I click the button, I need the code to repeat itself if I click the "not yet" button, if I click quit the program will end

I have tried to enclose the code in a for loop and the add one more cycle each time "timethingy" was activated but nop. so this is my last hope. my code:

```
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk



def timethingy():
 print("HI")
 time.sleep(3)
 root = Tk()
 root.title('aaaa?')
 root.geometry('400x300')
 root.config(bg='#F2B33D')

 frm = Frame(root, bg='#F2B33D')
 frm.pack(expand=True)
 def combine_funcs(*funcs):
   def combined_func(*args, **kwargs):
     for f in funcs:
        f(*args, **kwargs)
   return combined_func

 Label(frm, text="Hello World!").pack(pady=50)

 Button(frm, text="Not yet", command=combine_funcs(root.destroy, timethingy)).pack(side=LEFT, padx=20)
 Button(frm, text="Quit", command=root.destroy).pack(side=RIGHT, padx=20)
 timethingy()
 root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want.  Also why do you call `timethingy()` before `root.mainloop()`? It will cause recursion issue and `root.mainloop()` will never be executed.

Comment: I know, thats what I want to fix

Comment: You don't need to call it.

Comment: If I, for example, delete the function and replace it will go for a defined amount of time, I want the program to run as long as I click the button

Comment: so i need to call it

Comment: That is why I said *"It is not clear what you want"* because I don't understand why you need to call it there.  Also your posted code does nothing because `timethingy()` has never been called outside the function.

Comment: I want the program to run as long as I click the button, I need the code to repeat itself if  I click the "not yet" button, if I click quit the program will end

Comment: Then you need to call `timethingy()` outside the function, not before `root.mainloop()`.